# Setting ESlint as formatter in VSCode settings.json - what is the proper way?

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I see 2 options to set Eslint as my default formatted and I'm not sure on the difference between these options:

1. `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"`
   or
2. `"eslint.format.enable": true`

What is the difference between these 2 settings?

Answer (score 6):

`"eslint.format.enable": true` basically tells VSCode to use ESlint as a formatter for files that are validated by ESLint and to make sure it always uses your default favourite Prettier formatter, you use `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` as there can be multiple formatters installed.

Comment: And if both are set, would I have a conflict when formatting a file?

Comment: No. Its totally fine to set both the values.

Comment: One says to format via eslint and the other says to format via prettier.
who will 'win'?

Comment: Sorry my bad. As per eslint documentation, It says `you need disable other formatters if you want to make this the default`. The best way to have only one default formatter is to use this `"[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint" }`

Comment: VSCode will simply prompt you to pick one if you have multiple configured, FYI.

Comment: I recommend adding `"editor.formatOnSave": true` to the `[javascript]` block too as it'll automatically fix fixable issues for you.